# Can't put 2 images in a row with flex

Tags: css, flexbox

I can't manage to place in a row horizontal 2 images by using flex. I made sure there was enough space in the parent element.
They will just remain in column.

```css
.card {
  width: 50%;
  height: 90%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img src={htmlLogo} alt="html" width="72px" height="72px">
  <img src={cssLogo} alt="css" width="53px" height="74px">
</div>
```

Comment: From your example it would seem other styles are overwriting those applied as the code above is correct. Check what is being applied using the browsers web console. Also `flex-direction: row` is the default and can be omitted unless overriding.

Answer (score 0):

It aligns horizontally.

```css
.card{
    width: 50%;
    height: 90%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div className="card">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/72" alt="html" width="72px" height="72px"></img>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/53x74.png" alt="css" width="53px" height="74px"></img>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the images to stack on top of eachother?

If that's the case, you can try `flex-direction: column;`

```css
.card {
  width: 50%;
  height: 90%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img src={htmlLogo} alt="html" width="72px" height="72px">
  <img src={cssLogo} alt="css" width="53px" height="74px">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, react was actually not happy with the className "card".
I don't know why because i'm not using this class anywhere else.
Maybe created a conflict with Bootstrap?

Anyway, thanks guys for the help!